# Extend one div (among others) beyond parent container

Tags: html, css

I have a certaing layout of nested divs. One of them I would like to expand beyond its parent. However, with this nesting it's not that simple - I think.

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridcontent">
        <div class="gcrow single-column">
            <div class="gccolumn">
                <div class="gccolumn-inner">
                    <div class="gcitem">
                        <p>Extend to .wrapper width</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't change the html, and there may be other `.gcrow`s that need to stay inside the container. Is this possible to to at all?

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7L0tgu8b/1/).

I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current HTML structure you can use `.gcrow:first-child` and set `min-width: 100vw` which is same as `wrapper` width if you remove default margin and padding from `html, body`.

You can use `position: relative`, `left: 50%` and to make it center just add `transform: translateX(-50%)`, here is [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/7L0tgu8b/3/)

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px!important;
  padding-right: 20px!important;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
.gridcontent {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1018px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.gcrow {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.gcrow:first-child {
  min-width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gridcontent">
    <div class="gcrow single-column">
      <div class="gccolumn">
        <div class="gccolumn-inner">
          <div class="gcitem">
            <p>Extend to .wrapper width</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gcrow single-column">
      <div class="gccolumn">
        <div class="gccolumn-inner">
          <div class="gcitem">
            <p>Leave me alone</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also its `box-sizing: border-box` not `box-border`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
.gcrow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.gcitem {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It kind of makes the layour freak out. :-)